# Dockkerfile has some error

Tags: dockerfile

The following docker file:

```
ADD http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/audit/libaudit0_1.7.18-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb /
RUN dpkg -i  /libaudit0_1.7.18-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

gives me the following error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: `/libaudit0_1.7.18-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive /libaudit0_1.7.18-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /libaudit0_1.7.18-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: shouldn't you use a relative path for the `dpkg` argument? Maybe that'll do, as your CWD might not be /

Comment: i have used like this, even though iy is showing same error while building the Dockerfile                                                                        ADD http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/audit/libauparse0_2.3.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb /usr/src/things/
RUN dpkg -i /usr/src/things/libauparse0_2.3.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Comment: what does `file /usr/src/things/libauparse0_2.3.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb` yield in that context?